# How to change arbitrary input variable in shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, interactive

I'm trying to implement zoom-in feature in plot (usual ggplot2 and base R plot) used in shiny renderplot module. Here is the code.

```
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1",
             brush = "plot_brush"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, xlim = c(input$plot_brush$xmin, input$plot_brush$xmax), ylim=c(input$plot_brush$ymin, input$plot_brush$ymax))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here I want to set the input : - `input$plot_brush` to `NULL` after the zoom is applied. I know this will be requiring modification in the `renderPlot` block of the code but apart from that how can I set `input$plot_brush` to `NULL` [which will make the selection disappear from the plot]. I know update input functions are there in order to update UI [like `shiny::updateSelectInput()` etc] but those can't be used here for this purpose. 
Right now only one way to solve this is to have a base plot and a zoomed plot where zoom will be applied after selecting a region on base plot [as implemented in [https://gallery.shinyapps.io/105-plot-interaction-zoom/]](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/105-plot-interaction-zoom/).

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly setting the brush to NULL is just to remove the blue brush selection?

If so you can do it like this:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1",
             brush = brushOpts("plot_brush",resetOnNew=T),
             dblclick = 'dblclick'
  )
)

#
# Zoom in on plot brush, restore zoom on dbl click
#
server <- function(input, output) {
  ranges <- reactiveValues(x=NULL, y=NULL)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, xlim = ranges$x, ylim=ranges$y)
  })
  # Set limits for zoom
  observe({
    brush <- input$plot_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) { ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax); ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax); } 
  })
  # Zoom out on doubleclick
  observeEvent(input$dblclick,{
    ranges$x <- NULL; ranges$y <- NULL; 
  })
}
#
# Zoom in on dbl click, restore zoom on dbl click
#
server2 <- function(input, output) {
  ranges <- reactiveValues(x=NULL, y=NULL)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, xlim = ranges$x, ylim=ranges$y)
  })

  # Set ranges for plot zoom
  observeEvent(input$dblclick,{
    brush <- input$plot_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) { ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax); ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax); } 
    else{ ranges$x <- NULL; ranges$y <- NULL; }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here I'm using reset on new to remove the brush selection after zoom.

`Server` shows how you can zoom in by simply brushing (dbl click to zoom out) and

`Server2` shows how you can zoom in by doubleclicking on the brushed area to zoom in, dbl clicking with no brush zooms out.

Hope this helps!